# RTP Packets - c# code

Tags: c#, audio, sip, rtp

How can I convert a .wav file to RTP packet and send it to a sip Client? I would really appreciate some example code.

I'm working in C#.

Comment: Do you have any SIP code running at all at the moment?

Comment: yes. I code works till after ringing. I used RTP.net and i can't hear any real voice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you encoding/decoding the wav file with a particular codec before sending and receiving? Either way, the RTP packets that are received need to be directed to an output source. That source can be speakers, headset, or file.